# Does creating a new Database instead of just a new Collection provide any performance benefits in MongoDB 4.4?

Tags: mongodb, concurrency

I'm creating a Collection for storing chat messages. This Collection will be read and written very frequently. Should I create a new Database and create my chat Collection there, or just create my chat Collection in my existing Database?

I've read that WiredTiger only uses document level locks. Does this mean there will be no performance difference between the two mentioned options?

Comment: Database is a grouping of related collections. In general, a database can have data related to an application. But, a large application with lots of data and functionality can have multiple databases. Performance and multiple databases? Hundreds or more of databases means more files and organization on the disk - that is an overhead.  Also, tell about what you mean by: _"... my existing Database"_

Comment: @prasad_ My existing Database is the Database my application currently stores everything in. It contains 12 collections. I think creating a new chat Collection there makes a bit more organizational sense. So if performances are equal, I want to go with that.

Comment: If your chat collection data is used within the same app that is using the current database, it sounds logical to have chat data within the same database.